# How to load a script on $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I load a JavaScript with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://uads.ir/l.php?s=125125&w=5307cd5c027373e1773c9869"></script>
```

after page has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {

 });
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try appending the script to the head section: ([Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3gqh/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<script/>',{type:'text/javascript', src:'http://uads.ir/l.php?s=125125&w=5307cd5c027373e1773c9869'}).appendTo('head');
 });
```

EDIT: I like this syntax better..

Comment: if i want use it in a sample div i should use $(#sample).apeend ... ?!

Comment: @user3261715 what is this code meant for? is it a plugin, library, etc?

Comment: no i just use this code on a div advertise area!

Comment: @user3261715 I'm not really sure I get you.. there's not much meaning to placing a script inside a specific div.. can you give an example of what would the javascript file look like? (now it's blank)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to create the script tag, then its type and src attribs like this:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
```

Straightforward and semantic.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `script` tags after all of the HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://uads.ir/l.php?s=125125&w=5307cd5c027373e1773c9869",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `getScript()` method to achieve this. Documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Usage:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: This is what I originally had, but I did a double-check and remembered that this method adds a time-stamp to the URL preventing caching.  As such, you need to use the low-level $.ajax() function in order to leverage browser caching.